# Tcpdump to usb drive

Tags: ubuntu, tcpdump

Packets are being generated at 750 packets/second and I am using tcpdump to capture these packets and write them to file stored in a usb drive. Due to write speed limitations, the overall process of packet capture -> write to file takes a longer time. I would like to know what happens when I use Ctrl+C to terminate the tcpdump process. Will it write the captured packets to the file and then exit or will it immediately exit without writing the remaining captured packets to the file ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> results in the signal SIGINT being sent to the process. I believe it is up to the shell what happens after that so you should not depend on anything.

But your script can trap the signal and then perform tasks defined by you before it exits. Write a function that performs whatever action you want to take. The name doesn't matter. Here I called it cleanup. Then trap SIGINT and have the function called. Like this:

```
trap cleanup SIGINT

cleanup() {
   .... # your code here - to be executed after Ctrl+C/SIGINT is received

   exit 1  # <--- make sure you exit, otherwise Ctrl+C will not work anymore
}

... your script here...
```